Windows takes a long time to discover a folder on the local network after a failed connection
I have an SMB server running on my Synology NAS.
I also have a PPTP VPN on the router.
Both VPN and SMB are located at my home.
If I try to connect to the SMB from the WAN while forgetting to connect to the VPN, Windows logically gives me an error that it cannot access the specified address. However, the problem is that even when I connect to the VPN, it gives the same error. I have to wait about 5-7 minutes or completely restart the pc, only then Windows successfully connects to SMB.
Initially I thought the problem was with the VPN, but then the exact opposite happened. I was connected to a different VPN service at my home PC. Trying to connect to SMB, I of course got an error. Disconnecting from the VPN I again had to wait about 5 minutes for Windows to be able to connect to SMB again.
That is, this problem occurs regardless of whether I am trying to connect through the VPN or directly from the LAN, and it also appears on all the PCs that I have tested this on.
It only appears after I fail to connect to SMB. That is, if I initially connect from the WAN and connect to my VPN beforehand, everything is fine.
After doing some searching on the internet, all I found were suggestions to delete data from the credentials manager, as well as deleting connections via net use \\name /DELETE, however this did not help.

“I have to wait about 5-7 minutes.” 5-7 minutes after what? After forgetting to connect to the VPN?

@security_paranoid, after connecting to VPN, obviously.

If you connect by hostname instead of IP address, your device could be caching the wrong DNS value for your SMB server - fixable by running ipconfig /flushdns. You can use ping servername to see if the IP address your PC thinks the server has is correct

@Cpt.Whale, no, am using IP address.

Even when SMB is failing to connect, can you ping the server or do you have no connectivity with it at all? Are there other lan devices that work fine across the VPN while this is happening?

@Cpt.Whale, thats wierd. NAS IP is 192.168.1.105. When SMB is failing to connect, i cannot ping it as well, BUT i can successfully open the web interface of my NAS at http://192.168.1.105.

What is the ping failure reason? And just to make sure, ping does succeed when smb is working, right? There are some smb session/cache things that can cause similar behavior, but pings failing too would rule that out. Try dis/re-connecting both the vpn and your lan/wifi interface instead of rebooting? Since it sounds repeatable, it might be worth using wireshark to see if A) the traffic is going out the correct interface, or B) whether the nas gets the traffic and attempts to respond.
